# How to create a comment box in asp.net MVC using partial post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, renderpartial

I want to create a comment box in MVC. It should convert the text string from text box into label field and display on screen. We will be doing partial posts, as we don't want entire page to be posted back to server.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax callbacks (for example, $.ajax, https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of posts. Use javascript to do that.

Comment: can you provide some example on how to achieve this